# Passing variables from a function to a query string on link click

Tags: function, hyperlink, click, query-string

I need to pass some variables in a query string after it's run through a function once I click on a link.

So this is what I thought should happen:

```
<a href="/Print.aspx& + 'vars'" onclick="collectPrintOptions();" target="_blank"><strong>PRINT MY COVERAGE OPTIONS</strong></a>
```

And my javascript function:

```
function collectPrintOptions() {
        var url="&James=Male"
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: I got it. Simple  one.

In the function I add window.location and attach my variables to it.

Comment: Is there a way to answer my own questions on SO so that I can mark it correct?

Comment: Yes, you can answer your own question and mark it correct. But you can't upvote it.